Spring boot 3.2 upgrade and compatibility with Redis
We are doing spring boot upgrade to 3.2.0 with java 17
There is Redis dependency which loads during autoconfiguration and can interact with remote redis-cache (from PCF readymade service)
But we are getting below error whenever there is call to redis using Spring JPA
500 Server Error for HTTP GET \"/amdp/userActionsSummary\"","exception":"org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1805)\n\tSuppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: \nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ com.syf.presto.app_metrics.exception.advice.AppMetricsExceptionHandler$$Lambda$2190/0x0000000802105460 [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ com.syf.presto.app_metrics.exception.advice.AppMetricsExceptionHandler$$Lambda$2189/0x0000000802105238 [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ com.syf.presto.app_metrics.exception.advice.AppMetricsExceptionHandler$$Lambda$2188/0x0000000802105010 [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ com.syf.presto.app_metrics.exception.advice.AppMetricsExceptionHandler$$Lambda$2187/0x0000000802104df0 [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ com.syf.presto.app_metrics.exception.advice.AppMetricsExceptionHandler$$Lambda$2186/0x0000000802104bc8 [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ com.syf.presto.app_metrics.exception.advice.AppMetricsExceptionHandler$$Lambda$2185/0x00000008021049a0 [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET \"/amdp/userActionsSummary\" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]\nOriginal Stack Trace:\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1805)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1736)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1538)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.lambda$getConnection$0(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1518)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.doInLock(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1478)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1515)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1199)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1006)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.fetchConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:194)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:143)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:104)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:393)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:373)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:360)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.get(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:281)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$findById$3(KeyValueTemplate.java:241)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:314)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.findById(KeyValueTemplate.java:239)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.findById(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:98)\n\t\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\t\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)\n\t\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)\n\t\tat jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy248.findById(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\t\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\t\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)\n\t\tat jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy248.findById(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat com.syf.presto.app_metrics.utility.UserProfileHelper.getSystemDetails(UserProfileHelper.java:37)\n\t\tat com.syf.presto.app_metrics.handler.UserActionsHandler.getUserActionsSummary(UserActionsHandler.java:61)\n\t\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:61)\n\t\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleRequestWith(DispatcherHandler.java:206)\n\t\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handle$2(DispatcherHandler.java:154)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:138)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2331)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:503)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:411)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2051)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:305)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2331)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:437)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:471)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2051)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:264)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)\n\t\tat \
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

`

is that the full stacktrace?

I just added the trace logs
